# Sql Server Stored Procedure for adding columns to a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I m trying to create a stored procedure that will add two columns onto the end of a table. The SP takes 3 inputs, a table name, a state, and a school year.

When I run the SP I get an error:

```
The name "CA" is not permitted in this context. Valid expressions are constants, constant expressions, and (in some contexts) variables. Column names are not permitted.
```

Here is my SP:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_addScoolEnrollYear 
    @state nvarchar(2),   
    @shcoolYear nvarchar(15),
    @tableName nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql=   N'alter table ' + quotename(@tableName) + 
               N'add StateEnrollID varchar(2) default ' + quotename(@state) + N'not null,
                     SchoolYearKey varchar(20) default ' + quotename(@shcoolYear) + N'not null'

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql
END
GO
```

This is how I execute:

```
[dbo].[sp_addScoolEnrollYear] N'CA', N'2014-2015' , N'[dbo].[test_copy]'
```

Comment: Treat that error as a blessing in disguise.  If you don't know what database normalization is, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: I'm not trying to normalize my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were adding extra square brackets around the table name, and you need to use `'` instead of square brackets around your strings, and some more spaces between words, and each column added needs to be a separate alter:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_addScoolEnrollYear 
    @state nvarchar(2),   
    @shcoolYear nvarchar(15),
    @tableName sysname
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @Sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @Sql=N'alter table ' + @tablename 
       + N' add StateEnrollID varchar(2) default ''' + @state + N''' not null;' +char(10)
       + N'alter table ' + @tablename 
       + N' add SchoolYearKey varchar(20) default ''' + @shcoolYear + N''' not null;'
    select  @sql;
    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Sql;
END

END
GO
exec [dbo].[sp_addScoolEnrollYear] N'CA', N'2014-2015' , N'[dbo].[test_copy]'
```

code generated:

```
alter table dbo.test_copy add StateEnrollID varchar(2) default 'CA' not null;
alter table dbo.test_copy add SchoolYearKey varchar(20) default '2014-2015' not null;
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/HEKC53724

Comment: Can you take a look, I used a longer name for my table and I get an error,
http://rextester.com/EBM64134

Comment: @spitfiredd Updated